# How to add contribution line like sankey diagram to bar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, sankey-diagram

I want to combine one bar plot with Sankey diagram to show the contribution of each bar's mean value to each group. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

d = {'country': ['country1']*3 + ['country2']*2 + ['country3']*3,
     'province': ['province1']*3 + ['province2']*2 + ['province3'] + ['province4']*2,
     'type': ['type1', 'type2', 'type3'] + ['type1', 'type3'] + ['type2'] + ['type2', 'type3'],
     'value': np.arange(8),
     'error': np.arange(8)/5,
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Each country has several provinces that have estimated value/error from different types.

```
country province    type    value   error
0   country1    province1   type1   0   0.0
1   country1    province1   type2   1   0.2
2   country1    province1   type3   2   0.4
3   country2    province2   type1   3   0.6
4   country2    province2   type3   4   0.8
5   country3    province3   type2   5   1.0
6   country3    province4   type2   6   1.2
7   country3    province4   type3   7   1.4
```

Then, I plot the bar plot by `province` and `type` group:

```
# groupby province and type
df_province_grp = df.groupby(['province', 'type']).agg(mean=('value', np.mean), std=('error', np.mean)).reset_index()
# calcualte error bar
df_province_grp['std'] *= df_province_grp['mean']

# # reshape the dataframe into a wide format for Values
vals = df_province_grp.pivot(index='province', columns='type', values='mean')#.reindex(df_province_all.index)

# reshape the dataframe into a wide format for Errors
yerr = df_province_grp.pivot(index='province', columns='type', values='std')#.reindex(df_province_all.index)

# plot vals with yerr
ax = vals.plot(kind='bar', yerr=yerr, rot=30, figsize=(20, 6), alpha=0.7)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

[image: Bar plot]

I want to add the contribution of each province to countries at the bottom of the bar plot. I know Sankey diagram works for this function. Is it possible to combine these two figures into one using matplotlib or plotly?

```
df_province = df.groupby(['country', 'province'], as_index=False).agg({'value':'mean', 'error': 'mean'})#, 'plume_id': 'count'}).rename(columns={'plume_id': 'count'})

label_list = list(df_province[['country', 'province']].melt().drop('variable',axis=1)['value'].drop_duplicates().values)

# get the country name list in the order of country emissions
index_country = len(df_province['country'].drop_duplicates())
country_list = label_list[:index_country]

# create colors based on cmap and length in the order of emission values
country_color = plt.get_cmap('viridis_r', lut=len(country_list))
province_color = plt.get_cmap('Reds_r', lut=len(df_province))

if isinstance(province_color, matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap):
    province_color = [mcolors.rgb2hex(province_color(i)) for i in range(province_color.N)]
else:
    # set color based on all landfill emissions
    province_color = [to_hex(c) for c in province_color.colors]

sort_index = np.argsort(np.argsort(-df_province['value'].values))
province_color = [province_color[i] for i in sort_index]
country_color = [to_hex(c) for c in country_color.colors]

source = df_province['country'].apply(lambda x: label_list.index(x))
target = df_province['province'].apply(lambda x: label_list.index(x))
emission = df_province['value']

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    orientation = 'v',
    node = {"label": label_list,
            'color': country_color+province_color,
            },
    link = {"source": source, "target": target, "value": emission}
    )]
    )

fig.show()
```

[image: Sankey diagram]